# no matches for kind "ComputeAddress" in version "compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networking

I am trying to create a Google-managed SSL certificates for Google Kubernetes Engine (*v1.20.8-gke.900*) for that I have referred to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#config-connector) here it is says to create a **ComputeAddress** resource. So I have created a below config file

```yaml
#compute-address.yaml
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeAddress
metadata:
  name: my-app-lb-ip
  namespace: my-app-ns
spec:
  location: global
```

Now when I am applying it by running

```
kubectl apply -f compute-address.yaml
```

I am getting an error

> error: unable to recognize "compute-address.yaml": no matches for
> kind "ComputeAddress" in version
> "compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1"

So can anyone tell what should be the correct `apiVersion` or `kind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced and got the same error as you. Keep in mind that my original cluster was built from default values, meaning I just gave my cluster a name from UI and created it.

[It looks like you might have missed one step:](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#config-connector)

> Note: This step requires Config Connector. Follow the installation
> instructions to install Config Connector on your cluster.

The following cluster should give better results

```
gcloud container clusters create NAMEOFCLUSTER \
    --release-channel regular \
    --addons ConfigConnector \
    --workload-pool=PROJECTID.svc.id.goog \
    --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
    --zone us-central1-c
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, if you have a cluster already deployed you can update it with

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --update-addons ConfigConnector=ENABLED
```